# Count distinct values in Python list

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have a datagram like below

```
lable                          unigrams                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
ham    [ive, searching, right, word, thank, breather, i, promise, wont] 
spam   [free, entry, 2, wkly, comp, win, fa, cup, final, tkts, 21st, may]
```

I want to count the distinct/ unique ham unigrams and distinct spam unigrams.

I can count the distinct values in a column using `df.unigrams.nunique()`.
I can count the number of occurrences of a given unigram in ham using `unigramCount = unigramCorpus.loc["ham", "unigrams"].count('ive')`

But how can I count the number of distinct values in a given list? Ex:  `["ham", "spam"]`

Expected output:
ham = 9
spam = 12

Comment: And what would be the expected output?

Comment: just the count in number

Comment: Now I am confused. What is cell ? are we dealing with excel here? Post your expected output to make it simpler

Comment: there are 9 ham unigrams in the above. Therefore, I want the count 9 as the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
df.assign(count = df.unigrams.apply(lambda x: len(set(x))))

   label    unigrams                                          count
0   ham     [ive, searching, right, word, thank, breather,...]  9
1   spam    [free, entry, 2, wkly, comp, win, fa, cup, fin...]  12
```

Comment: Will this count the redundant words/ unigrams also? I want to ignore the redundant

Comment: Since, we are taking `set()` duplicates would be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

**Using `np.unique`**
(counts only distinct words in every list of unigrams, so duplicates will be ignored):

```
df['counts'] = df.apply(lambda x: len(np.unique(x['unigrams'])), axis=1) 
print(df)

>   label   unigrams    counts
0   ham [ive, searching, right, word, thank, breather,...   9
1   spam    [free, entry, 2, wkly, comp, win, fa, cup, fin...   12
```

Answer (score 0):

unigramCount = len(set(eval(unigramCorpus.loc["ham", "unigrams"])))

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but this might work:

```
df['count'] = df['unigrams'].map(lambda x: len(x))
```